Can I use Process Substitution with Visual Studio Code terminal tool?
I was trying to do something like
code --diff <(cat file1.txt) <(cat file2.txt)

But I get BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
The same using diff works
diff <(cat file1.txt) <(cat file2.txt)


This (specifically process substitution support for code --diff) was the subject of feature-request Allow to diff contents from the command line #54238, and closed as "out-of-scope" in 2018, with the following comment (emphasis added):

This issue is being closed to keep the number of issues in our inbox on a manageable level, we are closing issues that are not going to be addressed in the foreseeable future: We look at the number of votes the issue has received and the number of duplicate issues filed. If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider.
If you wonder what we are up to, please see our roadmap and issue reporting guidelines.

Aside: If it's any consolation to you, when I try what you're trying on a DEB installation on Ubuntu, it opens as a binary file, and trying to reopen it with a text editor causes a crash.

Is there any chance that it can be re-opened?

@Leandro yes. you can raise it as a feature-request. If you do so, 1) link to #54238 in your new issue ticket, 2) explain why you think it's crucial. what is your use-case? why can't this be achieved with extensions? (if you know how to answer that), and 3) comment here with a link to your issue ticket so I can follow it.
